# make windows form Title at The middle of the tittle bar

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

In My windows form application I want to make the title of the form in the middle of it's bar ( Title bar ) for example :
if you are on windows xp and open your my computer you will find it in the left of the title bar I want for example to make my title in the middle of the same bar

How ?

Comment: Step 1: Install [Windows 8 DP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516). Step 2: Done. It's ugly.

Comment: :D I already installed it but I want it to my old application one of My customers want it in the middle :D

Comment: Is there a reason they want your app to behave differently from every other app they'll ever use?

Comment: You'll have to paint it yourself which is horribly hard to do.

Comment: Microsoft Office does this so I think it is a valid request to have an application display the title centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically three options:

1. Create a custom control that has the title centered and the appropriate minimize/maximize/close buttons.  Use a from with no title bar and drop your custom control on top.
2. Use GDI+ to draw the title, and update its position using form resize events.  Total hack, not even sure this would work.
3. Calculate the number of spaces required to center the title based on the width of the form and then insert them before the title text.  Lame solution, but it would work and be easy to implement.

Comment: #3 is probably the best HACK to get it to look centered, I would add one thing to it though.  You need to calculate the number of spaces every time the window is resized and do it using DrawString and the frame size to figure out how many spaces you need.

Comment: No. 1 isn't going to work. As for no. 2, there's so much more to custom painting the non-client area. No. 3 is complicated by not knowing how big the non-client chrome is. It would take a degree of effort to work that out.

Comment: I don't know why you say #1 won't work.  I've built custom windows this way before and there are many examples on the web.  It actually works quit well.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible using regular WinForms form properties. On the other hand, you can create a form without any border and custom draw your own borders. That will be very much like what other skinning libraries too so you can look into various skinning libs from vendors if you don't want to bother with writing your own custom routines.

Comment: Skins is the best way. But another is get the OnSize message and set the caption with leading spaces.